# Add click listener for multiple geojson-objects javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to set click listeners on many different shapes on my map. Each shape has a bunch of data which I want to show when I click on it.

```
var newData = new google.maps.Data({
    map: map,
    style: map.data.getStyle()
});
for (var i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
    var userObject = JSON.parse(shapes[i].area);
    newData.addGeoJson(userObject);

    // It would be simplest to add a clicklistener here since i got access to the shapes[i] with the data to act on
    google.maps.event.addListener( /* ??? */, 'click', function (event) {
            alert("y");
        });
}
map.data.setMap(null);
map.data = newData;
```

I tried setting the click listener on the returned array from addGeoJson(...) but maybe im approaching this wrong. Maybe I need to get polygons somehow and then go about it like in this [official example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer) or Im thinking I could do something hacky with different layers.

How would you do this, given that you cannot change that you get a bunch of separate geoJson chunks? Can I get my geoJson as polygons when I'm adding them?

Answer (score 1):

The way forward I will use which I think will work out well is:

[addGeoJson](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/data#Data.addGeoJson) returns an array of features. Use [setProperty(name, newVal)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/data#Data.Feature.setGeometry) on them and add the information later required by the clicking action. Retrieve the data by [getProperty(name)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/data#Data.Feature.getProperty)

Add a click listener on the entire data object:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(newData, 'click', function (event) {
    event.feature.forEachProperty(function (value, name) {
        alert("name: " + name + "value: " + value);
    })
});
```